# How to shutdown pygame in windows 8?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I was doing a small experiment with Python in my new win8 install and found the following issue:

Code:

```
import pygame, sys

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1280,960])
myball=pygame.image.load("Globe.png")
screen.blit(myball, [576, 416])
pygame.display.flip()
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit
```

However when I hit the 'X' button on the pygame window nothing happens. Is this just a win8 issue or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general practice is to also call pygame.quit() when looking to exit the program.  See below:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

EDIT - also this is probably not a complete copy/paste of your code, but if your code literally just says sys.exit without the () it is not a function call :)

Comment: actually the best practice, is to let the python code, finish itself, this would involve a break in the while loop. Then pygame.quit calls itself.

Comment: In the interest of self-education, why is breaking the While-loop preferable to calling pygame.quit() and sys.exit() on an exit event?  Just a code-once use-many sort of thing or what